# How does AutoShardedBot work in discord.py?

Tags: python, sharding, discord.py

Would someone explain how sharding works, specifically `discord.ext.commands.AutoShardedBot`?
I put multiple questions below:

- Does it run on multiple servers?
- If not, how is it beneficial to shard it?
- Do guilds sometimes switch between shards?
- How do I use one database if the bot runs on multiple servers?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If by "multiple servers" you mean physical machines, no, it's a
   single python instance.
2. Discord requires sharding past 2.5k guilds.
3. Guilds are assigned to shard by `(guild_id >> 22) % shard_count`
4. Make the database accessible over the network, be sure to secure it
   with a strong password, connect to it from each.

if you need to split it to multiple machines, you can pass `shard_id` and `shard_count` to a normal `Bot` instance.

[Discord Docs on Sharding](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#sharding)

Comment: If it runs on only one host, what is the benefit to sharding?

Comment: I'm very confused. Let me try to make my question clear: If I shard my bot, does that mean it is running on one *host*, or multiple hosts? I know that a single shard has multiple guilds, but I don't understand if you put one shard per host, or multiple shards on one host.

Comment: It doesn't mean one or the other. If you shard across multiple hosts, then it's running on multiple hosts. if you shard in a way that's not across multiple hosts, then it's not.

Comment: What is the benefit to putting multiple shards on one host? Why would you ever do it?

Comment: If you have no memory/CPU issues, then you can simply use AutoSharded and run it all in the same process
If you are having CPU issues, but not memory issues... you can run shards on multiple processes
If you are having memory issues, you're going to need to shard across multiple hosts

The latter two options require you to communicate between the processes in some way. The first wouldn't, since it's all in one, everything is handled internally so you don't have to even think about it being sharded